# How to ensure that all documents are signed by all?

Tags: docusignapi

If envelop having multiple document and send it to multiple person for sign in.
Can we disable "FINISH" option still the person sign in all document inside envelop ?

Currently In my case if the person sign the one document the "FINISH" option is enable.

Please let me know if I am missing something.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The finish button does not work until the signer recipient has signed all of the required signature tabs.

But note that the signer can elect to "finish later."

Your application can determine if the signer has started to sign but has not finished signing--if the signer's status is `delivered` then this is the case. (If a signer recipient's status is `complete` then they've finished signing.)

You can then send your own messages to the signer for them to finish signing if you wish. Or often better, you can alert a human in your organization that the signer started to sign but didn't yet finish. For example, alert the salesperson responsible for the sale.